# How to Visualise Neural Network with weights in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, visualization

I'm working on a problem where I am using neural networks. I wanted to visualise my neural network with input layers, hidden layers and their weights (something like this : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxnQl.jpg) ).

Libraries I am using for my neural network sknn.mlp (Regressor, Layer).

Thanks.

Comment: I think that you are looking for something like print.nn un R using package [neuralnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf) you can get the structure of your network after the training and  using [calling-r-from-python](https://sites.google.com/site/aslugsguidetopython/data-analysis/pandas/calling-r-from-python) you can pass the structure to paint. I've never tested this so I will look forward you solve this. On other hand you can create a paint.nn for a community. Take a look for Tensorflow and Theano  maybe can help you

Comment: Thanks @Cyberguille for promising leads. I will let you know if this works